# Discord.js bot help needed - how can I make my bot auto do a task every 6 hours without sending it a command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a bot with a command that auto assign roles to members based on stats I get from an API. How do I make it so that it does that automatically every 6 hours or so without me sending a command manually?

Comment: If you have all the params you require, you can probably use `setInterval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can do something like that:

```
setInterval(function(){
client.channels.get("Channel Id").send("I will send it every 6 hours")
  }, 6 * 3600000);
```

You need to use it in event ready.

Comment: Or you can use cron-job a package the allows you to execute something in schedule [Cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)